# Visual Studio: Per-solution extension sets and/or keyboard shortcut sets

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, add-in

I work on both native C++ and .net applications using all of the Visual Studio versions from 2010 to 2015 (depending on the project). When I work in C++, I like to have Visual Assist X enabled, ReSharper disabled, and a variety of keyboard shortcuts mapped to VAX functions. When I work in .net, I like to have ReSharper enabled, Visual Assist X disabled, and many of the same keyboard shortcuts mapped to equivalent R# functions. For hybrid applications I pick one or the other, depending on which language dominates and what I'm doing specifically.

Going back and forth between the two configurations manually takes a lot of time. Is there a way to store different keyboard shortcut sets and/or enabled extension sets so I can quickly switch back and forth between these two configurations? Bonus if the configurations could be stored with the solution such that VS switches automatically when it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate Visual Studio configurations using the [/rootsuffix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166507.aspx) command line parameter.